# Lightsail avoid direct IP navigation through HTTP

Tags: http, https, amazon-lightsail

I have a full working **Lightsail** instance.

I successfully configured and bind to it my custom domain and, in order to use **SSL**, I created a **Distribution** with the associated certificate. Since I want to avoid using **HTTP**, in the DNS records I mapped my domain not to my static IP, but to my distribution.

Everything is working fine and if I navigate to **[www.exemple.com](http://www.exemple.com)** I am redirected to **https://www.exemple.com**

The problem is that my server is still accessible from outside the **distribution** through **HTTP** and if I navigate to its IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, I reach it via **HTTP**.

Is it possible to avoid to reach the server from outside the **distribution** or to avoid it allow **HTTP**?

Thank you in advace!